# POSIX named semaphore name without slash

Tags: posix, semaphore

The man page `sem_overview(7)` explains that the name of named semaphores ought to start with `/`. However, I couldn't find any specification of what should or would happen if such a name does not start by a slash.

Trying it out on Linux seems to reveal no difference at all and `xxd /dev/shm/sem.mysem` also shows no difference when using `sem_open("mysem", 0)` vs. `sem_open("/mysem", 0)` in a (C) program.

Is the naming scheme actually of any relevance?

Comment: From [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html): *If name does not begin with the `<slash>` character, the effect is implementation-defined*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:**

The GLIBC implementation ignores leading `/` characters despite what the documentation says.

**Full answer:**

Per [POSIX `sem_open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/sem_open.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <semaphore.h>
>
> sem_t *sem_open(const char *name, int oflag, ...);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ...
>
> If `name` does not begin with the <slash> character, the effect is
> implementation-defined.
>
> ...

So, in this case the name will be treated per [the Linux `sem_open()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `sem_open()` creates a new POSIX semaphore or opens an existing
> semaphore.  The semaphore is identified by name.  For details of the
> construction of name, see
> [sem_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html).

Which brings us back to the [`sem_overview(7)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) as you noted:

> **Named semaphores**
>
> A named semaphore is identified by a name of the form
> /somename; that is, a null-terminated string of up to
> `NAME_MAX-4` (i.e., 251) characters consisting of an initial
> slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which
> are slashes.

As you noted, that doesn't specify what happens if the leading `/` is omitted.

So, how is it implemented?

The actual name of the semaphore file (that's all a "POSIX named semaphore" is - a file in a file system that is memory mapped and contains a semaphore object) is created in GLIBC by the [`__shm_get_name()` function in the `posix/shm-directory.c` file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.38.9000/source/posix/shm-directory.c#L30):

```
int
__shm_get_name (struct shmdir_name *result, const char *name, bool sem_prefix)
{
  struct alloc_buffer buffer;
  size_t namelen;

  buffer = alloc_buffer_create (result->name, sizeof (result->name));
  alloc_buffer_copy_bytes (&buffer, SHMDIR, strlen (SHMDIR));

#if defined (SHM_ANON) && defined (O_TMPFILE)
  if (name == SHM_ANON)
    {
      /* For SHM_ANON, we want shm_open () to pass O_TMPFILE to open (),
         with SHMDIR itself as the path.  So, leave it at that.  */
      alloc_buffer_add_byte (&buffer, 0);
      if (alloc_buffer_has_failed (&buffer))
        return -1;
      return 0;
    }
#endif

  while (name[0] == '/')
    ++name;
  namelen = strlen (name);

  if (sem_prefix)
    alloc_buffer_copy_bytes (&buffer, "sem.", strlen ("sem."));
  alloc_buffer_copy_bytes (&buffer, name, namelen + 1);
  if (namelen == 0 || memchr (name, '/', namelen) != NULL)
    return EINVAL;
  if (alloc_buffer_has_failed (&buffer))
    {
      if (namelen > NAME_MAX)
        return ENAMETOOLONG;
      return EINVAL;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Note this code:

```
while (name[0] == '/')
    ++name;
```

The code skips over all leading `/` characters if they exist.  If there are no leading `/` characters, GLIBC proceeds without error.

GLIBC's implementation makes leading `/` characters use irrelevant.  The result is the same no matter how many leading `/` characters are used, even if that number is zero, despite what the `sem_overview` man page states.